# Google Billing - SUBSCRIPTION_PURCHASED event - what is the point?

Tags: android, google-pay, in-app-subscription, google-play-developer-api

I am working on implementing Google Billing (Subscriptions) in my app.
(https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions).

The basic flow is that a registered user, uses their Android app to purchase a subscription and receives a PREMIUM account.
My backend server is the source of truth regarding the user account's current plan.

I am using Real Time Developer Notifications (RTDN) to keep my backend server up to date with changes to the user's subscription.

The flow I have is as follows:

1. User purchases the subscription in the Android mobile app.
2. After the sub is purchased, the app sends a POST request to my backend-server, that contains the `purchaseToken` and I create the subscription entity in the database, acknowledge the purchase with the google server and unlock all the content for the user.
3. Whenever the subscription is renewed, cancelled etc. I handle those events with appropriate listeners.

The things is - between 1 and 2, I also receive a notification from google of type `SUBSCRIPTION_PURCHASED` that I ignore.
My question is - what is the point of this event? The event does not contain any useful information for me, it has the purchase token, but I wouldn't be able to assign this PREMIUM account to any user based on this event, because it doesn't have any user-specific data.

Therefore I have to rely on my POST request in point 2. to actually be sent and not fail, otherwise I am in trouble, because the customer has paid and I have not saved the subscription / unlocked the content.

It would be ideal I think to have some sort of user-related data sent by google in the notifications. Is that possible? If not, really what is the point of the `SUBSCRIPTION_PURCHASED` event?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, I have done the same in my app,
You can pass the user-related info in the below method of the BillingFlowParameter.Builder while launching billing flow from Android app.

[setObfuscatedAccountId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.Builder#setObfuscatedAccountId(java.lang.String))

[setObfuscatedProfileId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.Builder#setObfuscatedProfileId(java.lang.String)).

Once you receive RTDN from google at your backend, pass the received purchase token to the below call, and you can find the passed user info in the **ExternalAccountIdentifiers** field.

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptionsv2